# C++ unique character check

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have my following code in which for unique check part whatever input i give its saying that all are unique characters. Is there any thing i missed logically in case 2 ??

```
***case 2: {
{
for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)

for(int j=1;j<counter;j++)               //I THINK THIS US WHERE SOME THING WENT WRONG
{                                        // LOGICALLY. WHAT IS THAT THAT HAS TO BE 
                                         //CHANGED.
if(array[i] == array[j]) { flag == 1; }
else flag = 0;
}
}
if(flag == 1) { cout<<"\n All characters in the sentence are not unique"; }
else if(flag == 0) { cout<<"All are unique characters"; }
};break;***        
}
```

Comment: i think compiler should have warned you about the no-effect code `flag==1`?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things wrong, firstly:
flag == 1 is a comparison, not an assignment, so your flag will never be set to 1 in your case.
secondly, j should not start from 1 but from i+1.

On a side note, you set the flag with every check so essentially you are only checking the last comparison.
you probably want to early out of your loop when you found out that a character is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong:

first I think the inner loop should be

```
for (int j=i+i; j<counter; j++)
```

otherwise, let's say in case of i=2  you will compare array[2] with itself (if j and i are both 2)

Also, regarding the flag, you should not set it back to 0 whenever you find different characters (leave out the `else` clause), because finding differring characters somewhere does not mean, to reset the flag that you've seen equal ones.  Instead set `flag= 0` before the first loop.

EDIT: And, as others have pointed out, setting the flag is done with "=" not, with "==", so we have at least three bugs there.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` condition should be `(i!=j && array[i]==array[j])` and `flag == 1` is not an assignment but a comparison and should be changed to `flag = 1`.

Instead of changing the `if` condition you may also start counting the `j` at `i+1`. My suggestion for the rewritten code looks like this

```
bool flag = false;
for(int i=0; i<counter && !flag; ++i)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<counter; ++j)
    {
        if( array[i] == array[j] ) 
        { 
            flag = true;
            break; // exits the inner for loop only.
        }
    }
}
cout << flag ? "\n All characters in the sentence are not unique" :
    "All are unique characters";
break; // exits switch statement.
```

Comment: :chuckles.  Now you're using the "flag== true" assignment in your own solution.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered you have couple of mistakes in the code,

1. `flag = 1`
2. for check condition.....  `i!=j && array[i] == array[j]`

But ideally the unique character check of this sort is not the most optimized solution. You would need an int array of size 255 all of its contents initialized to zero. For each character encountered, go to the ASCII value position and increment the value by 1. Once this is done, cross check in the array if there exists any member with values other than 0 or 1. If encountered there exists a duplicate in the string !